# Проблемы с входом в кошелёк Gui Wallet после обновления v0.18.1.0

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-rpc, cold-storage, wallet-recovery, wallet

16.08.2022 мне были отправлены монеты, но в своём графическом кошельке GUI я их так и не увидел. На сайте монеты https://www.supportxmr.com/ увидел сообщение что 13 августа прошло обновление сети монеты, и что нужно обновить свои кошельки до последней версии, так как в старой версии транзакции будут не видны. И действительно, уже второй день кошелёк мне показывает уведомление с предложением обновиться до v0.18.1.0. версии, поэтому я решил загрузить обновления. Но после этого я не смог вообще попасть в свой кошелёк! После ввода пароля вижу сообщение кошелька "Невозможно открыть кошелёк: failed to read file"C\Users\пусть к моему файлу кошелька .keys"! Если вернуть к старой версии v0.17.3.2 то войти снова получается, но монет нету. Тех поддержку кошелька не нашёл, что делать не знаю. Кто-нибудь столкнулся с подобной проблемой? Любой информации буду рад.

Comment: Could you please ask your question in English? Thanks

Comment: Точно такая же проблема, но у меня не получается восстановить кошелек через фразу

Comment: Все перепробовал. У меня выдает ошибку, если пытаюсь восстановить кошелек в версии 0.18.1.0
Не знаю что делать вообще

Comment: У меня такая же проблема, не получается восстановить кошелек даже со старой версии. Подскажите у Вас получилось восстановить?

Answer (score 0):

У тебя проблемы с .keys файлом. Придётся восстанавливать кошелёк. Думаю стоит попробовать следующее:

1. Забекапь текущий файл .keys на случай если что-то сломается.
2. Открой .keys в старой версии приложения (v0.17.3.2)
3. Иди в Settings->Show seed & keys и перепиши Mnemonic seed и Wallet restore height
4. Запусти новую версию приложения (v0.18.1.0) и выбери "Restore wallet from keys or mnemonic seed"
5. Введи туда Mnemonic seed и Wallet restore height
6. Жми next и жди пока синхронизируется.

Это должно помочь воссоздать кошелёк если файл перестал читаться в новой версии. Если после восстановления транзакции не появятся, то смотри на какой адрес отправил.